# Android - Get source code of a page that needs login

Tags: java, android, authentication, jsoup

I'm trying to get the source code of a page that needs user login.

I need this to make an android application.
I already tryed jsoup with POST session cookie and then GET but that ends in an force close.
I also tryed DefaultHttpClient and that ends in that i'm not logged in.
The login works but when I want to load the profile page it brings me back to the login page. The login is lost and I don't know why. When I use DefaultHttpClient and stays in the same client and then do a post it gives me an error on console that the connection needs to be close before request a new page.

What I need is this. Login on page http://www.example.com/login then I need the source code of the page that is like http://www.example.com/profile

When you logged in on the website you will be redirect to example.com when it fails you will go again to the login page.

What do I need to do to let it work on Android, not in Java i've already done it in java but that code fails in an Android app becouse it won't holds it's cookies

I'm programming it for android 2.3.3 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DefaultHttpClient, you'll need to set the cookie store if you want to hold on to the session token for your request to the profile page.

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    CookieStore cookieJar = new BasicCookieStore();
    httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieJar);
```